Prometheus Histogram Export format fqnames for additional metrics, such as max, min, ...?
The Prometheus documentation on histogram metric types describes the export format used as follows:

A histogram with a base metric name of <basename> exposes multiple time series during a scrape:

cumulative counters for the observation buckets, exposed as <basename>_bucket{le="<upper inclusive bound>"}
the total sum of all observed values, exposed as <basename>_sum
the count of events that have been observed, exposed as <basename>_count (identical to <basename>_bucket{le="+Inf"} above)


(emphasis in the original text)
Now, I'm taking samples and maintaining my own histograms outside Prometheus' Go client module, only using prometheus.MustNewConstHistogramWithCreatedTimestamp(...) for export. In my use case I also want to export further information related to these histograms, such as "min" and "max" samples seen.
Now this doesn't seem to be covered by Prometheus; what is accepted/best practice in terms of fqnames for such additional, directly histogram-related metrics? Is it acceptable to use <basename>_min, <basename>_max, et cetera?
